# How can I write function to merge two records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have database structure

```
--car_id 
--from_date_time
--to_date_time
--is_booked
```

I want to do :

```
If any two records having is_booked == 'N" exists in database, having overlapping from_date_time and to_date_time, 
then these records will be merged into a single record.
```

Example:

```
If i have records in database like:
Record 1:
from_date_time = '2016-08-01 04:00:00';
to_date_time = '2016-08-01 06:00:00';

Record 2:
from_date_time = '2016-08-01 03:00:00';
to_date_time = '2016-08-01 05:00:00';

Then,above two records will get merged to create following:
from_date_time = '2016-08-01 03:00:00';
to_date_time = '2016-08-01 06:00:00';
```

I have tried following :

```
i) Check if the looped_from_date_time is in any database record with from_date_time >= looped_from_date_time  and to_date_time <= looped_from_date_time  and is_booked = "N" and car_id = $car_id.

   iii) Check if the looped_to_date_time is in any database record with from_date_time >= looped_to_date_time and to_date_time <= looped_to_date_time and is_booked = "N" and car_id = $car_id.
```

But it is not working

Comment: Could you please define your schema and data on http://sqlfiddle.com ? That will be make everything easier for us.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

'Period1' overlaps 'Period2'

```
if

NOT ( end_of_period1 < beginning_of_period2 OR 
beginning_of_period1 > end_of_period2).
```

This is the only way to cover all possible situations.

In your case I believe that the first condition (I) is always false : 
if `'from_date_time'` is always inferior to `'to_date_time'` in all records, you cannot have `"from_date_time >= looped_from_date_time  and to_date_time <= looped_from_date_time"`.